# How to hide static library inside of a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks, clang

I am building a private framework that depends on a static library. The library let's call it **LibNet** is embedded inside of dynamic framework let's call it **MyFramework**.

[Xcode framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56hnO.png)

When MyFramework is imported inside of an client App I want to prohibit the user of MyFramework to import LibNet and use it inside of their App.

Desired result ( inside of client app ):

`import MyFramework`

`import LibNet` ( Error: module not found / module is private )

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tokgV.png)

Important info:

- LibNet is a swift static library
- MyFramework is a Objective-C dynamic library with Swift source code
- Both are built for iOS
- Both use swift version 5.0
- Both use iOS version 12.1

Question:

1. Is the thing I am trying, possible?
2. Is it possible to restrict LibNet usage by specific target?

---

Comment: No reason to downvote, not vote to close. But can you post more? Some code that can reproduce what you need - and the issue you have?

Comment: @dfd I have added some images for reference. If the question is still confusing for some let me know.